# When Generate Signed APK :Error:(131) Error: Expected resource of type styleable [ResourceType]

Tags: android, styleable

Error occure in this 
/*        // UserProfile
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));*/
        // Payment
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Invite friends
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Help
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));

```
    //Trip History

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
```

here is my Code complete:
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewDrawer);
        mToolbar = ((NavigationActivity) getActivity()).getToolbar();

```
/*  mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);*/

    // load slide menu items
    String[] navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    TypedArray navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);


    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);

    ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
```

/*        // UserProfile
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));*/
        // Payment
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Invite friends
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Help
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));

```
    //Trip History

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
```

//        driver mode on/off

```
    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getActivity(),
            navDrawerItems);

    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerListView
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    selectItem(position);
                    adapter.setSelectedItem(position);
                }
            });


    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    adapter.setSelectedItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this (work for me)**

- Add this line to your build.gradle file

> android {
>
> ```
>   lintOptions {
>      disable "ResourceType"}
> ```
>
> }